# Can't import python packages in R reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I have tried absolutely everything I could think of to try and figure this out. I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXm8hPKFYCQ) exactly, created a new conda environment, installed the packages I want to use, and tried to import the packages. I get this error when I try to import the python packages:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: use() got an unexpected keyword argument 'warn'
```

After 5 hours I am completley lost and have no idea what to do. I am following exactly what the individual is doing in the video. This is unbelievably frustrating.